# Gre consecutive even integers question

Tags: sequences-and-series, median

The sum of $101$ consecutive even integers is $20,200$.

I'm stuck on proving that their average and median, they are actually equal by the answer.

Notice average is $\frac{20200}{101} = 200$, and the pattern
$$x , x + 2, x + 4, \dots$$
But how do I find the median through this, any help?

Comment: Aren't the average and median always the same for an odd number of numbers in arithmetic progression?

Comment: They are equally spaced so the distribution is symmetric, and so the $51$st is the average of the all of them

Comment: @J.W.Tanner - some people might say the median is an interval if there are an even number of terms (not here)

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990264/mean-and-median-of-an-arithmetic-progression)